# Configuring Network in Linkit 7688 (OpenWRT)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, openwrt

I'm new to networking and openWRT. I just compiled an openWRT version but the wifi module was absent. To transfer a new firmware i tried to work around the network settings and get the ethernet to the master mode. But doing so also cancelled my wifi connection. Now i want to make this configurations permanent (in case of broken firmware again to somehow connect w/ SSH) but with a viable internet connection through wifi. My config files and *ifconfig output* are below. Also i am using an *openWRT 3.18.23* kernel.

```
 etc/config/network :

config interface 'loopback'
    option ifname 'lo'
    option proto 'static'
    option ipaddr '127.0.0.1'
    option netmask '255.0.0.0'

config globals 'globals'
    option ula_prefix 'fd6b:f1eb:9a25::/48'

config interface 'lan'
    option force_link '1'
    option macaddr '9c:65:f9:23:a9:cf'
    option type 'bridge'
    option proto 'static'
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option ip6assign '60'
    option ipaddr '192.168.100.1'

config switch
    option name 'switch0'
    option reset '1'
    option enable_vlan '0'

config interface 'wan'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option proto 'dhcp'
    option macaddr '9c:65:f9:23:c3:33'



etc/config/wireless :

config wifi-iface
    option device 'radio0'
    option network 'wwan'
    option mode 'sta'
    option ssid 'myssid'
    option encryption 'psk2'
    option key 'mykey'
    option disabled '0'

config interface 'wwan'
    option proto 'dhcp'

config zone
    option name 'lan'
    option input 'ACCEPT'
    option output 'ACCEPT'
    option forward 'ACCEPT'
    option network 'lan wwan'

config wifi-device 'radio0'
    option type 'ralink'
    option variant 'mt7628'
    option country 'TW'
    option hwmode '11g'
    option htmode 'HT40'
    option channel 'auto'
    option disabled '0'

config wifi-iface 'ap'
    option device 'radio0'
    option mode 'ap'
    option network 'lan'
    option ifname 'ra0'
    option encryption 'none'
    option ssid 'LinkIt_Smart_7688_23C333'
    option seq '1'

config wifi-iface 'sta'
    option device 'radio0'
    option mode 'sta'
    option network 'wan'
    option ifname 'apcli0'
    option led 'mediatek:orange:wifi'
    option encryption 'psk2'
    option ssid 'XXXXX'
    option key 'XXXXX'
    option disabled '0'

config wifi-device 'radio1'
    option type 'mac80211'
    option channel '11'
    option hwmode '11g'
    option path 'platform/10300000.wmac'
    option htmode 'HT20'
    option disabled '1'

config wifi-iface 'default_radio1'
    option device 'radio1'
    option network 'lan'
    option mode 'ap'
    option ssid 'OpenWrt'
    option encryption 'none'

ifconfig :

br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9C:65:F9:23:A9:CF  
          inet addr:192.168.100.1  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fd6b:f1eb:9a25::1/60 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::9e65:f9ff:fe23:a9cf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:336 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:34384 (33.5 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9C:65:F9:23:C3:33  
          inet6 addr: fe80::9e65:f9ff:fe23:c333/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1425 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:479164 (467.9 KiB)
          Interrupt:5 

eth0.1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9C:65:F9:23:A9:CF  
          inet6 addr: fe80::9e65:f9ff:fe23:a9cf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:6937 (6.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5952 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5952 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:404736 (395.2 KiB)  TX bytes:404736 (395.2 KiB)

ra0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9C:65:F9:23:C3:33  
          inet6 addr: fe80::9e65:f9ff:fe23:c333/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:78158 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5995 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:16156893 (15.4 MiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:6
```

I am looking for a way to learn and accomplish this. Either there is no good documentation on this or i simply don't understant what i am reading. Any help/comment/suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my own solution. I just needed to add an interface to /etc/config/network and configure /etc/config/wireless according to it.

I added ;

```
/etc/config/network
config 'wan2'
     option proto 'dhcp'
```

And configured ;

```
/etc/config/wireless
config wifi-iface 'sta'
    option device 'radio0'
    option mode 'sta'
    option network 'wan2'
    option ifname 'apcli0'
    option led 'mediatek:orange:wifi'
    option encryption 'psk2'
    option ssid 'XXXXX'
    option key 'XXXXX'
    option disabled '0'
```